# Change Image when Page Refresh in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is on of tough task that am facing in my school. am totally new to angularJs. i need to fetch one image out of all retrieved images from the database. And then when i refresh the page the next image want to appear.

for an example first "banner.jpg" appear when i refresh the page "banner1.jpg" want to appear. can anyone help me to do solve this problem. please.

This is my retrieved Json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner3.jpg"
  },
```

my angular controller.

```
appGM.controller('bannerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'urls', function ($scope, $http, urls) {
var request = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: urls.api + 'Banner/Banners'

}).success(function (data, status) {

    console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));

    $scope.BBanner = angular.fromJson(data);

})
 .error(function (error) {
     $scope.status = 'Unable to load dog images: ' + error.message;
     console.log($scope.status);
 });
```

And its my Html

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav" ng-repeat="d in BBanner">
                        <img ng-src="{{d.path}}">
    </div>
```

Comment: use localstorage to store old id of image then compare and use next image

Comment: thank you for your comment brother. i'm new to angular. can you please say how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use localstorage to store the in in the first time. After you refresh the page increment the value and save it to the same local storage and so on.

run this [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ONenuXOwi54b2V2MXMW?p=preview) multiple time to see the id change.

controller

```
 if(!localStorage.getItem("uID")){
    var s = {"id":1};

    localStorage.setItem("uID", JSON.stringify(s))
  }
    $scope.data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner3.jpg"
  }]


 var item = localStorage.getItem("uID")
 item = JSON.parse(item);
 alert("Id = " + item.id)

 item.id = item.id +1  ;

 localStorage.setItem("uID", JSON.stringify(item))

 $scope.clear = function(){
   localStorage.removeItem("uID");
 }
```

updated

add this to check the image. check the demo again

```
 var item = localStorage.getItem("uID")
 item = JSON.parse(item); 

 var obj = $scope.data.find(function(o){
   return o.id === item.id
 }) 
 // add this lines 
 $scope.image =(obj)? obj.path : "invalid id";
 if(item.id == 4){
    localStorage.removeItem("uIDs");
    item.id = 0;
 }
 item.id = item.id +1  ;
```

Comment: +1 for your 2nd  comment to my quetion. dont mistake me brother  am new to angular. can please tell how can i use it into my code. i need to change the images.

Comment: @Coderszone tech check the demo again

Comment: @Coderszone tech no prob bro :D

Comment: cant loop firstimage again without clearing the localstorage?

Comment: without  clicking the clear button //{localStorage.removeItem("uID");}//


after the the banner3.jpg appeared again the banner.jpg {1st image} need to appear. is that possible??

Comment: @Coderszone tech check the demo again

Comment: nothing changed bro. it still showing the invalid id.

Comment: that's what am asking. without clearing the storage can i show the first image again?

Comment: check again i change the storage name

Comment: for your note can you help me to solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037658/angularjs-change-image-when-page-refresh-otherwise-if-not-refreshed-want-to 
thank you.