# angularJS: Change Image when Page Refresh. otherwise (if not refreshed) want to change automatically in 5 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here am created one page with **Image changing** while the **page refresh**.
from this SO question [Change Image when Page Refresh in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948044/change-image-when-page-refresh-in-angularjs/42948767#42948767). Now i need to **change the image**  **automatically** after the 5 seconds, which means the page refreshed or not the image want to change. How can i solve this issue by implementing this following code. please help me...

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("uID")){ var s = {"id":1};

    localStorage.setItem("uID", JSON.stringify(s))
  }
    $scope.data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner3.jpg"
  }]


var item = localStorage.getItem("uID")
 item = JSON.parse(item); 

 var obj = $scope.data.find(function(o){
   return o.id === item.id
 }) 
 // add this lines 
 $scope.image =(obj)? obj.path : "invalid id";
 if(item.id == 4){
    localStorage.removeItem("uIDs");
    item.id = 0;
 }
 item.id = item.id +1  ;
```

This is My Html

```
 <body>
   <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     {{image}}
   <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
</div>
  </body>
```

Here is working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/5ONenuXOwi54b2V2MXMW?p=preview

Comment: show your html also

Comment: i have edited my question. please help me brother and thanks in advance.

Comment: use setInterval when assign imagepath .

Comment: well am new to angular. dont know how to add that. will you please tell me for how to add this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use timeout function to show the image after 5 seconds.

```
init();
function init(){
  for (var i=0;i<=$scope.data.length-1;i++) {

      setTime(i)
  }
}
function setTime(i){
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.image = $scope.data[i].path;
    if (i == $scope.data.length-1) {
       init()
    }
  }, (5000 * i));
}
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$timeout){
 
    $scope.data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner3.jpg"
  }]
    
    
  
 init();
 
  function init(){
    for (var i=0;i<=$scope.data.length-1;i++) {
      
        setTime(i)
    }
  }
  function setTime(i){
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.image = $scope.data[i].path; 
      if (i == $scope.data.length-1) { 
          init();
      }
    }, (5000 * i));
  }
 
 $scope.clear = function(){
   debugger
   localStorage.removeItem("uIDs");
 }
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

     <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
       {{image}}
      <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: i need both parts want to work which means. Change Image when Page Refresh and (if not refreshed) want to change automatically in 5 sec. can you please implement that too.

Comment: its showing the old plnkr only its not updating for me. can u edit that part into your answer.

Comment: @Coderszone tech localstorage not support in SO code snippet check this one https://plnkr.co/edit/z7lnSqVwrKl98e9lBVJg?p=preview

Comment: the refreshing part is not working propely. i checked it several times. but its not working

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: when i refreshing the page, the same number repeating several times. (means for an example banner1 is showing multiple times). its not changing properly. may i know why is that??

Comment: i think you forgot to add  item.id = item.id + 1;

            localStorage.setItem("bID", JSON.stringify(item))  These two lines. and add it into the plunker. its working nicely

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then you are looking for this,,

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("ctrl",function($scope, $timeout){
   $scope.data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner.jpg"
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner1.jpg"
   },
   {
    "id": 3,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner2.jpg"
   },
   {
    "id": 4,
    "path": "Content/Banner/banner3.jpg"
   }]


   var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

   $scope.image = $scope.data[k-1].path;
   var obj = $scope.data[k];
   setImage();

   function setImage(argument) {
    
    $timeout(function () {
     if (obj.path) {
      if (obj.id >$scope.data.length) {
       $scope.image = getImage(obj.id);
       obj.id = 1;
      }else{
       $scope.image = getImage(obj.id);
       obj.id ++;
      }
     }else{
      $scope.image = "invalid id";
     }

      setImage();
     }, 5000)
   };

   function getImage(id) {
    for (var i = $scope.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if ($scope.data[i].id == id) {
      return $scope.data[i].path;
     }
    }
   }


  })
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{image}}
  <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the working [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sorb999/hoee75zq/)

Comment: use $timeout instead of settimeout

Comment: well thanks for your answer. i need both parts want to work which means.  Change Image when Page Refresh and (if not refreshed) want to change automatically in 5 sec

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal sorry its not working for me.  can you provide a working plunker.

Comment: click on Run Code Snippet again and again you will find it

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal when am refreshing, sometimes the same number is repeating several times. may i know why is that?

Comment: this is because I am taking random number between some value. So it mat be possible that same number can appear more than once..

Comment: if i want to change the images according to ascending order how can change your code? because, am implementing two web pages, when user jump one page to another the banners also need to change. if it is not changed there no any use with this task. thats why am asking. really sorry if am embarrassing you.